# Norm bound of a complex resolvent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, norms

A well known result by [Varah](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379575901123/1-s2.0-0024379575901123-main.pdf?_tid=786f5ba4-bf05-11e3-83e5-00000aacb360&acdnat=1396951776_38ac851412895bd3ba8e2820335a96e4) states that if $A$ is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix of dimension $n$, then 
$\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty} \le \max_i\frac{1}{|a_{kk}|-\sum_{j \neq k}|a_{kj}|}$, where the infinity norm here is the induced $\ell_{\infty}$, i.e. $\max_{k}\sum_{j}|a_{kj}|$.

Let us assume that $A$ is real and Hermitian, with eigenvalues in $[-a,a]$, all distinct. I am trying to bound the infinity norm of the following resolvent:

$$
B = \left( \delta i I - A \right)^{-1}
$$

where $\delta$ is small, so $\delta i I -A$ is not necessarily diagonally dominant. Naturally, $\delta i I -A$ is always invertible. I denote $i$ as the imaginary unit and $I$ the identity matrix.

A trivial upper bound would be $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\delta}$. Do you see any circumstances for which a better bound may be attained?

Thank you.

**Edit**: A bound of $\epsilon$ to the above question is equivalent to asking whether for all matrices $E$ with $\|E\|_{\infty} \le \epsilon$, $i\delta$ is not an eigenvalue of $A+E$.

Generally, $\epsilon$ will be a function of both $\delta$, $\|E\|$ and the condition number of the eigenvalue matrix of $A$. However, subject to the above restrictions, do you see a better bound?

Comment: What is $i$? The imaginary unit? The identity matrix?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm pretty sure from context it is the imaginary unit (multiplied by a copy of the identity matrix of the appropriate size)

Comment: @neil What other structure are you willing to put on your matrix $A$ (beyond trivial things like "being diagonal with real entries") in order to get "a better bound"? Generically I would think that since $\Vert A \Vert_\infty$ can be significantly bigger than $\rho(A)$ even when $A$ is Hermitian, the same phenomenon would occur for $\Vert B \Vert_\infty$

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, i is the imaginary unit. Thank you, I edited.

Comment: @YemonChoi, I am also willing to assume $A$ is a "shifted" doubly stochastic matrix. Namely, that $A = S -\alpha I$ where $A$ is stochastic and $\alpha$ is some real number in $[0,1]$.